# Create Google sign in activity

Tags: android, google-signin, google-authentication

I want to create an activity in which users will enter their Google username and password in order to access my app. I wonder if there is some Android apis that allow me to achieve this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth

Answer (score 0):

Do you really feel people will input their username and password inside you app, i wonder it would be great if they do.
Consider using Google Sign-In android or some OAuth.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyou.privacysecurity&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dapp+lock&pcampaignid=APPU_14_TNPXVp-YDcm-0gSgqqaQDQ this app lock will show you a forget password screen where you have to fill in your Gmail's username and password. How can the developer do that?